# Conditional references in .NET project, possible to get rid of warning?

Tags: c#, reference, project, conditional-statements, compiler-warnings

I have two references to a SQLite assembly, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit, which looks like this (this is a test project to try to get rid of the warning, don't get hung up on the paths):

```
<Reference Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' " Include="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\64-bit\System.Data.SQLite.DLL</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' " Include="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\32-bit\System.Data.SQLite.DLL</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This produces the following warning:

```
Warning 1 The referenced component 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be found.
```

Is it possible for me to get rid of this warning?

One way I've looked at it to just configure my project to be 32-bit when I develop, and let the build machine fix the reference when building for 64-bit, but this seems a bit awkward and probably prone to errors.

Any other options?

The reason I want to get rid of it is that the warning is apparently being picked up by TeamCity and periodically flagged as something I need to look into, so I'd like to get completely rid of it.

---

**Edit**: Per the answer, I tried this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    ...
    <SqlitePath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\32-bit</SqlitePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    ...
    <SqlitePath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\32-bit</SqlitePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    ...
    <SqlitePath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\64-bit</SqlitePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    ...
    <SqlitePath>..\..\LVK Libraries\SQLite3\version_1.0.65.0\64-bit</SqlitePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then in my reference:

```
<Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>$(SqlitePath)\System.Data.SQLite.DLL</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This got rid of the warning, but is it correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is no "AnyCPU" assembly for SQL Lite you are stuck with separate builds.

To do separate builds create a property that gives the correct path in a conditional property group and then use that property to have a single reference (i.e. move the conditional outside the references items group). There is an example of using such a property (for a custom FXCop extension) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx), you can see lots of conditional properties being defined at the start of the `.csproj` file.

(Summary: VS doesn't handle all of the possibilities MSBuild does.)

Comment: I've edited my answer with what I think is correct, can you look at it and tell me if that was what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the problem with your original project was that you had `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>` specifying `System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.61.0`, whereas the actual assembly was version 1.0.65. Fixing version in the assembly name in `Reference` ought to help.

Comment: Hmm, you have a point, although it generates a warning for both x86 and x64 though, and one of them is apparently correct. I'll look into it.

Comment: Apparently I have a problem with the files, the file was actually 1.0.61 in that case. The reference had been added manually through Visual Studio and thus should be correct. I'll fix the files though, but that wasn't the culprit for the warnings.

Comment: Two more suggestions — putt `Condition` on the `ItemGroup`, not on `Reference` itself; try absolute paths.

Comment: Putting the Condition in the ItemGroup doesn't help, just incase anyone runs into this. Visual Studio stupidly thinks you still have a reference on the assembly, even when your condition evaluates to false.